# Is there sofware that can emulate how Oracle works with disks?

Tags: software-rec, benchmarking, emulator

Don't now if its a right place to ask, so if not please give me a hint.
I need some software that do can emulate how Oracle works with disks (**Notice:** Not the Oracle workload tool).
I've already took a look at solutions kinda Benchmark Factory (Quest Software), SwingBench, etc., but they do not emulate.

Comment: Are you talking about oracle the OS? Or another specific piece of software developed by them?

Comment: I mean software that can emulets oracle DB commands, or something like that (kind of sqlio))

Answer (score 2):

Why not just grab [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html) ?

> Oracle Database 10g Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an entry-level, small-footprint database based on the Oracle Database 10g Release 2 code base that's free to develop, deploy, and distribute

Comment: I think you should learn English a little better - my question is not about DB, but about oracle emulator. Thank you for now.

Comment: @jammy Perhaps you should form your question better. From your comment: `software that can emulets`( *sic* )`oracle DB commands, or something like that` Why emulate a database when you can get it ?

Comment: Because I need to emulete it. KO?)

Comment: but ...  Why?  When you can have Express Edition for 100% compatibility, why go for a emulator with quirks or just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ORION is the tool your looking for. It generates Oracle like IO. The are several parameters you can set to generate a specific type of load (random io, sequential io) etc.
[orion](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-089595.html)